# What level do LLVM optimization passes need to work on?

Tags: optimization, llvm

I have been exploring LLVM Optimizations recently but have a small question:

How do we know that a built-in pass (not LLVM Passes that we write) can be applied at the function level (using a `FunctionPassManager`), or Module level, etc?

Example - As seen in the KaleidoScope tutorial 4:

```
TheFPM->add(createCFGSimplificationPass());
```

This one is fairly obvious that it should be at function level but what about other passes? Are they all meant to work at any level (BasicBlock, Function, Module, etc) correctly?

Comment: I would recommend you to make your question title more specific otherwise it is too broad.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , I've now changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can find that out by looking at the source code.
For example, [here](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/SimplifyCFGPass_8cpp_source.html#l00192) is code for SimplifyCFGPass which inherites FunctionPass and [here](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/MemoryDependenceAnalysis_8h_source.html#l00260) is the source code for MemoryDependencyAnalysisPass and as you can see it's a function level pass.

Comment: I'll upvote the answer after I've gained a reputation more than 15. Thanks a lot , it was helpful.